# Change recipe variable (e.g. EXTRA_OECMAKE) inside a bitbake task

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

Currently, I'm facing an odd requirement, where we have to put 2 slightly different binaries into the rootfs, and the **only** difference is the fact that we have an extra CMake option set for one of them.

So, the approach we took was to create a few extra tasks to be run, and add them in the correct sequence (after we copied the first binary). Everything works fine (renaming, having 2 bins, etc.).

The main issue is, we can't change `EXTRA_OECMAKE` during this custom `do_configure` task. I think it does make some sense that this is blocked... We actually *can* change it there using `d.setVar()`, although this is parsed before the whole recipe starts, so we still get 2 of the same.

Is there any nice approach that doesn't end up being:

1. Creating a new recipe with most of the data being copied over (or generalizing most on `.inc`  files)
2. copying the whole `cmake_do_configure` out of the `cmake.bbclass` just to force an extra variable when running `cmake`

Let's know if either 1) or 2) are the best options though :)

We're currently on kirkstone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) is the best solution where you're not fighting the system.  The easiest solution is a .inc file which is 99% of the recipe and then just set the relevant option in each of your recipe-foo.bb and recipe-bar.bb files.